# I am trying to return an array which holds the totals of all sublists in an array

Tags: java, arrays

but when i try to return the array it gives me a weird reference this is what is returned : The array is: [I@895684
I dont know why it isn't working, also i am unsure of how to include the total of sublists of array size a[1], a[2], a[3]... a[n-1]

```
import java.util.*;

class SumArray
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter some numbers (all on one line, separated by commas):");
  String line = input.nextLine();
  String[] numbers = line.split(",");
  int[] array = new int[numbers.length];
  for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
      array[i]=Integer.parseInt(numbers[i].trim());
  int[] highSum = highestSum(array);
  System.out.println("The array is: "+highSum);
 }

 public static int[] highestSum(int[] a)
 {
    // int[] array = new int[a.length];
     //int end = a.length - 1;
     int sum = 0;
     int[] highestSum = new int[a.length-1];
     for (int j=0; j<a.length - 1; j++) {

     for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
         sum = sum + a[i];
         System.out.println(sum + " " + a.length);
     } 
     highestSum[j] = sum;
     System.out.println(highestSum[j]);
    }
    return highestSum;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to include sublists of array size 1, 2, 3... n-1"? Where do you want to include "sublists"?

Comment: I still don't understand the second part of your question.

Comment: Hi, Im trying to include in the array that i return all totals of sublists in the original array for example; if i have {1,-5, 3, 5} then i want to include in the array {1, -5, 3, 5, -4, -2, 8, -1, 3, 4} this gives all the totals of sublists of size 1 :{1, -5, 3, 5} , sublists of size 2: {-4, -2, 8 }, sublists of size 3 = {-1}, sublists of size 4 {4} in one array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
int[] highSum = highestSum(array);
System.out.println("The array is: "+highSum);
```

will print the result you see. Use

```
System.out.println("The array is: " + Arrays.toString(highSum));
```

to print the content.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the logic for your requirement. This will append the maximum sum sublist in a single array and print it.

For printing an array you can use `Arrays.toString(highSum)`.
For concatenation of two array you can refer the method below `public static int[] concatArray(int[] A, int[] B)`

Note: This is brute force way. You can research on more optimal way of solving your problem ;).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out
            .println("Enter some numbers (all on one line, separated by commas):");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = line.split(",");
    int[] array = new int[numbers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i].trim());
    int[] highSum = concatArray(array, highestSum(array));
    System.out.println("The array is: " + Arrays.toString(highSum));
}

public static int[] highestSum(int[] a)
{
    // int[] array = new int[a.length];
    // int end = a.length - 1;
    int result[]=new int[0];
    for (int k = a.length-2; k >=0 ; k--)
    {
        int[] highestSum = new int[0];
        int maxSum= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int [] tempSum = new int[k+1];
            int index = 0;
            if(j+k<a.length)
            {
                for (int i = j; i <= j+k ; i++)
                {
                    sum = sum + a[i];
                    tempSum[index++]= a[i];
                }
                if(sum > maxSum)
                {
                    maxSum = sum;
                    highestSum = tempSum;
                }
            }
        }
        result = concatArray(result, highestSum);
    }
    return result;
}

public static int[] concatArray(int[] A, int[] B) 
{
       int aLen = A.length;
       int bLen = B.length;
       int[] C= new int[aLen+bLen];
       System.arraycopy(A, 0, C, 0, aLen);
       System.arraycopy(B, 0, C, aLen, bLen);
       return C;
}
```